# Does chronicle queue have problems rolling daily if I skip weekends?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

I have a process that runs at 1 am and is stopped at 11pm everyday using crontab. This creates a chronicle queue file everyday, and because cleaning up is tedious, I changed the crontab to only run on weekdays on Apr 14. Today Apr 17, I checked the files and I found:

[image: Files created]

For some reason, today it created a file for yesterday Apr 16, and then rolled over again for Apr 17? I m not using anything different for creating a queue.

```
QUEUE = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.single(prop.getProperty("CHRONICLE_PATH"))
                .rollCycle(RollCycles.FAST_DAILY).build();
```

edit: I just came in this week (24th April) and found this.

[image: it is still happening]

[image: the crontab i use]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have some data for the 16th. The default timezone is GMT so if you are in another timezone, you could see files that don't exactly match your local time.

Comment: I have changed the code to use `rollTime()`, i ll check back in again next week monday to see if it still makes a file for the day before. Much appreciated!

Comment: oh. I found out that the rollTime() is an enterprise feature. My team doesnt have the enterprise feature, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @chunkynuggy it improves manageability but is tricky to support e.g. Americas/NewYork or Europe/London have daylight savings changes, which is why its enterprise.